# how to expose server port in upstream block of Nginx configuration?

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

We have a handful of homogenous application loosely under `SOA` pattern. Because of homogeneity, we have been able to define some neat pattern in Nginx to proxy all of our `SOA` apps through one configuration. Following Nginx configuration is absolutely working absolute wonders in conjunction with `DNSmasq` to resolve `anything.yourdomain.devel` eg. `a.stackoverflow.devel`, `b.stackoverflow.devel` domains and route that to appropriate app servers under your project folder via designated ports via maps.

```
 worker_processes  2;

    events {
      worker_connections  1024;
    }

    http {

          map $host $static_content_root {
            hostnames;
            default /path/to/project/folder;
            # For typical standalone apps living in your project directory
            # *.myapp.local.devel -> /path/to/project/myapp/public
            ~^([^\.]+\.)*(?<app>[^\.]+)\.devel$ /path/to/project/folder/$app/public; #rails pattern
          }

          map $app $devel_proxy_port1 {
            default 3000;
            domain1 3000;         
            domain2 4000;

          }

          map $app $devel_proxy_port2 {
            default 3001;
            domain1 3001;
            domain2 4001;
          }

          server {
            listen 127.0.0.1;
            server_name  ~^([^\.]+\.)*(?<app>[^\.]+)\.[^\.]+.devel$;


            location / {
              root  $static_content_root; # Using the map we defined earlier
              try_files $uri $uri/index.html @dynamic;
            }

            location @dynamic {
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
                proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forward-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header X-Forward-Proto http;
                proxy_set_header X-Nginx-Proxy true;
                proxy_redirect off;
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:$devel_proxy_port1;
            }
          }
        }
```

Now, in order to simulate multiple servers behind **Nginx** load balancer. I thought of doing following proxy configuration which points to upstream rather than directly pointing to one server:port pair.

```
proxy_pass http://backend;

upstream backend {
   server http://127.0.0.1:$devel_proxy_port1;
   server http://127.0.0.1:$devel_proxy_port2;
}
```

I thought above would work but it always emits following error hinting the variables of **map** blocks are not available inside **upstream** context.

```
[emerg] 69478#0: invalid host in upstream "http://127.0.0.1:$devel_proxy_port1" in /usr/local/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:57
```

> Is this an expected behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, variable can not be used inside upstream. You can create few upstream blocks with different names (`upstream backend`, `upstream backend_domain`, etc), resolve upstream name through `map` and put this variable to `proxy_pass`:

```
upstream backend {
 server http://127.0.0.1:3000;
 server http://127.0.0.1:3001;
}

upstream backend_domain1 {
 server http://127.0.0.1:3002;
 server http://127.0.0.1:3003;
}

upstream backend_domain2 {
 server http://127.0.0.1:3004;
 server http://127.0.0.1:3005;
}

...

upstream backend_domain30 {
 server http://127.0.0.1:3060;
 server http://127.0.0.1:3061;
}

map $app $devel_proxy {
 default backend;
 domain1 backend_domain1;
 domain2 backend_domain2;
 ...
 domain30 backend_domain30;
}

...
proxy_pass $devel_proxy;
...
```

In some cases you can skip `map` block using `$app` inside `proxy_pass`: `proxy_pass backend_$app;`, but need additional checks for `$app` values. Also, `map` allow to to map different "domains" to same applications.

Comment: The whole point I was querying about is to get the parameterized port inside the upstream block. Every single app is assigned a pair of ports and the ports are taken from maps depending on name identifier of the domain eg. dmitry.stackoverflow.com has name dmitry on stackoverflow.com domain and there are many many names on stackoverflow mapped to a pair of ports. Does your answer suffice that scenario? I don't see how?

Comment: You will need to create separate `upstream` for each name identifier.

Comment: I understand it works if you have one app bound to 3000 and 3001 ports but within upstream, the port needs to a variable so that it could dynamically assign ports according to map block on $app. $app could have possible 30 different value based on first map block from first post. For brevity, i only showed two possible value to $app ie. domain1 and domain2

Comment: 30 different $app... each $app has separate port (or even two), right? domain1 - 3000, 3001; domain2 - 3002, 3003; ... domain30 - 3058, 3059? So you need to create 30 `upstream` blocks. Edited answer.

Comment: Yeah, that way it works. If only upstream block took variables, it could have achieved the same goal with single block given the pattern.

Comment: Separate upstream more flexible. For example, easy to add 3rd application instance to domain25 only. Also, if you are using same application instance for few domains - just `map` this domains to same upstream.